# Entity Framework Core to SQL Server IN Clause

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

We are converting from LINQ to SQL to Entity Framework Core 2.2 and are finding that the translation of Contains operations do not become IN clauses in SQL Server. What is happening is that EF Core is pulling back all of the data using the other conditions and then filtering it down locally. This is not acceptable. We can use EF.Functions.Contains but this requires us to enable Full Text Search in SQL Server, which is over kill.

Any idea how to get a statement like the following to translate to an IN clause in SQL Server?

```
var myValues = new [] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var qry = _context.Table.Where(t => myValues.Contains(t.TableProperty));
```

Okay, maybe I over simplified the code to keep it simple for the question. The actual code looks like:

```
voterQuery = voterQuery.Where(v => voterFilter.VoterStatus.Select(p => p.Value).Contains(v.VotStatus.ToString()));
```

What is happening in our code is that we are building up an `IQueryable` from user selections on a filtering screen. voterFilters contains a collection of these selection criteria. VoterStatus is one of the selection criteria which is a `List<CheckedListItem>`, which are from a Winforms `CheckedListItems` control.

The selection of p.Value returns a List of strings. I have tried to project the list of strings to an array, with the same results of the IN clause not being created or a server query. Perhaps, EF Core does not allow strings to be used for the IN clause values. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: The query in question *does* translate to SQL `IN`. You need to show the actual problematic query because there are other factors which may cause client evaluation.

Comment: I have edited the code to include the actual code where the IN clause was created in LINQ to SQL but is not doing so in EFCore. Any help/insight would be appreciated

Answer (score 7):

Currently (as of v2.2.3), EF Core requires the expression used for `Contains` to be a simple `IEnumerable<T>` variable (no LINQ operators) where the `T` is primitive type.

Which means you need to move the `voterFilter.VoterStatus.Select(p => p.Value)` into variable outside the query expression tree and use that variable inside:

```
var voterStatusFilter = voterFilter.VoterStatus.Select(p => p.Value);
voterQuery = voterQuery.Where(v => voteStatusFilter.Contains(v.VotStatus.ToString()));
```

Comment: Thank you Ivan. You're recommendation works. The issue was compounded by the fact that the scaffolding code created the property as a string rather than a char, which is what the underlying SQL Data is actually. When I changed my model to be a char for the VoterStatus the query translated into a SQL Server IN clause. Live and learn.